# Why does the double quote (") be parsed as (\") in conditional policy statement for S3 user policy while using AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-s3, sdk, subdirectory, policy, bucket

The requirement is to restrict the IAM user access to a specific subfolder within a S3 bucket through the AWS SDK.  It is much easier to config the user policy through the AWS console, but I failed when turned it into java code with the AWS SDK.

For example, I want the IAM user only be able to access the 'subfolder1' folder within the 'mybucket' bucket.
Here below is the user policy that can work perfectly with the AWS console:
(The solution itself kindly refer to [here](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke) - which I verified successfully in AWS console)

```java
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "subfolder1/"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/subfolder1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here below is the java code snippet to generate the above policy.

```java
// Attach the required permission user policy to the new user
// 1. Permission to list all the buckets (view)
final Statement allowListStatement = new Statement(Effect.Allow)
    .withActions(
            S3Actions.ListBuckets,
            S3Actions.GetBucketLocation
        )
    .withResources(new Resource("arn:aws:s3:::*"));

// 2. Permission to list the objects within the bucket
final String dq = (char)(34) + "";
final String prefix = dq + dq + "," + dq + "subfolder1/" + dq;

final Statement allowBucketListStatement = new Statement(Effect.Allow)
.withActions(
        S3Actions.ListObjects
    )
.withResources(
        new S3BucketResource(bucketName)
    )
.withConditions(
        new StringCondition(
                StringComparisonType.StringEquals,
                S3ConditionFactory.PREFIX_CONDITION_KEY,
                prefix
            ),
        new StringCondition(
                StringComparisonType.StringEquals,
                S3ConditionFactory.DELIMITER_CONDITION_KEY,
                "/"
            )
    );

// 3. Permission to update the bucket content
final Statement allowBucketOperationsStatement = new Statement(Effect.Allow)
    .withActions(
            S3Actions.PutObject,
            S3Actions.GetObject,
            S3Actions.DeleteObject
        )
    .withResources(
            new S3ObjectResource(
                    bucketName,
                    usernameIAM + "/*"
                )
   );

final Policy policy = new Policy()
    .withStatements(
            allowListStatement,
            allowBucketListStatement,
            allowBucketOperationsStatement
        );

final PutUserPolicyRequest policyRequest = new PutUserPolicyRequest(
        usernameIAM,
        "policy_subfolder1",
        policy.toJson()

    );
client.putUserPolicy(policyRequest);
```

The problem happens in the 'withConditions' line (all other policy lines are generated correctly except this line).

The expected line would be like this (which works fine in AWS console):

```java
"Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","subfolder1/"], "s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
```

But the actual generated line is this:

```java
"Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["\"\",\"subfolder1/\""], "s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
```

It is so weird that the AWS SDK somehow couldn't parse the double quote(") properly in the statement: all the double quote (") is parsed as (\").

The 'prefix' definition seems strange. In my original code, I was using this:

```java
final String prefix = "\"\",\"" + usernameIAM + "/\"";
```

But this gives the same problem as my current approach (using dq the ascii code).

I am not sure if it is a bug of the AWS SDK. Can any one throw any light to this issue?  Or any other approach or suggestion to implement my requirement (but has to be using SDK)?

---

Comment: `final String prefix = dq + dq + "," + dq + "subfolder1/" + dq;` <- *you* are adding the quotes yourself. The `\"` is how a `"` is escaped in JSON. Note the API is expecting a *value* and not 'manual JSON text'.

Comment: The real question is probably: "How can I use a multi-'prefix' with a StringCondition?"

Comment: The code in comments are totally messed up.  I attached my solution in the updated question.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Consider posting the 'updated' code as an answer, and explain how/why it solves the problem. (You can accept your own answers, and it will make the solution easier for others to find.)

Comment: yes, thanks for the suggestion.  I posted my solution to an answer post and removed it from the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user2864740 for the suggestion.  Hereby I just post my answer to the question.  Hope it might be easier for others to find.
As user2864740 pointed out, the API is expecting a value and not 'manual JSON text', the double quote (") will be parsed with a escaped format (\").

The solution is to split the StringCondition into different pieces instead of generating the JSON string manually.  Here is the final workable solution:

```
final String prefix1 = "";
final String prefix2 = "subfolder1/";
final Statement allowBucketListStatement = new Statement(Effect.Allow)
.withActions(
        S3Actions.ListObjects
    )
.withResources(
        new S3BucketResource(bucketName)
    )
.withConditions(
        new StringCondition(
                StringComparisonType.StringEquals,
                S3ConditionFactory.PREFIX_CONDITION_KEY,
                prefix1
            ),
        new StringCondition(
                StringComparisonType.StringEquals,
                S3ConditionFactory.PREFIX_CONDITION_KEY,
                prefix2
            ),
        new StringCondition(
                StringComparisonType.StringEquals,
                S3ConditionFactory.DELIMITER_CONDITION_KEY,
                "/"
            )
    );
```